# Can Android layout be loaded in the C language?

Tags: android, c, android-layout, android-ndk

[This link](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/declaring-layout#java) says that to make the app display a layout, you create a `main_layout.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello, I am a Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and then load it in `onCreate` method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // main_layout.xml is compiled into the R.layout.main_layout object
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
}
```

My problem is that I am coding in C, and have the C version of "onCreate" method:

```
JNIEXPORT
void ANativeActivity_onCreate(ANativeActivity *activity, void *savedState,
                          size_t savedStateSize) {
    ....
}
```

is it possible to load the layout and make the app display it in the C language?

Comment: Why not just have a regular Java/Kotlin activity class that calls JNI functions for the bits that need to be native? While in principle you can call `setContentView()` from your C function, you would also need to manipulate the inflated UI from C functions. This would seem like it would spiral into an unmaintainable mess fairly quickly.

Comment: Section "Why" of https://github.com/cnlohr/rawdrawandroid explains "why not have Java"

Comment: You need to find the C equivalents of `setContentView` and `R.layout.main_layout`.

Answer (score 2):

C uses "ANativeActivity" that it doesn't has any of Java methods and resources/objects. Even if you manually parse that XML you should MANUALLY implement all Widgets/Components in C.....so it's near impossible due to high amount of work involved in it.

Usually someone chooses C on Android to do "some special work" that is not available on normal Java or due to performance issues on it.

Comment: Tried creating an empty app with java, using the Android SDK with gradlew build. The **empty** app size is 7MB!!! Whereas with C, the app size is <200kB.

Comment: I know that (I suppose your "empty App" is in debug and not obfuscated, optimized and shrinked), but if you want use "ANativeActivity" you cannot use any Java SDK library/package and you need to create all by your own. Or you can use "Qt" libraries to get most of usual common Components/Widgets back, but these use their own methods to be controlled/used by a Developer.

Comment: PS: a quite big App in my "career", that doesn't use many external libraries that needs to be included in the project, generates an 1.7Mb file in Release mode after obfuscation and minimizing procedure. It's not so bad.